# Getting DB Server DateTime in application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

I am using Entity framework and have 1 field in database AddedDate that is DateTime and not null, so I need to pass DateTime value.

But the problem is I have to pass **DB Server datetime**. How can I manage in this sceario or how can I get **DB Server datatime** to pass this.

I need to some unique solution, because I am this on many forms.

**Edit:** I need DB server Datetime upon insertion/updation in my application so that I can pass to entity framework object.

Thanks

Comment: What is, for you, a `DB Server datetime`? Is that a SQL DateTime? Is that an SQL datetime? Or DB2, Oracle? Is that the internal datetime or something else? Do you have an example of such datetime vs a current date/time?

Comment: Do you mean the current time on the DB server when your insert/update operation is executed?

Comment: yes, I mean current Datetime of DB Server, when I am insering and updating

Comment: try the second answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200617/how-do-i-use-sqls-getdate-and-dateadd-in-a-linq-to-sql-expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using entity framework, you can do something like this:

```
var dateQuery = yourDbContext.CreateQuery<DateTime>("CurrentDateTime() ");
DateTime dateFromSql = dateQuery .AsEnumerable().First();
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you use the entity framework and you use DateTime in a field, it will automatically do the back/forth conversion for you, just the same way it does so for integers, doubles etc.

Unless you mean something special, i.e., a char[40] field that must be filled with a DateTime value of a particular format.

Comment: I need DB server Datetime upon insertion/updation, so that I can send the that Date & time from my application

Answer (score 0):

You can get database server date and time by running SELECT GETDATE()) script.

Consider you have a table with 4 colums - the first 3 being strings and the last datetime, You can solve your issue by issueing INSERT SQL like this:

INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('x', 'y', 'z', SELECT GETDATE())

Comment: I am using Entity Framework, do you have some knowledge about that?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a stored procedure so you can get DB server Datetime very easily.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework, do you have some knowledge about that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use getdate() in your query. For example:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (AddedDate, ...other columns) VALUES (getdate(), ...other values)
```

This basically asks the server to insert its own current date into the field; there's no need for you to retrieve it locally.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework, do you have some knowledge about that?