# Executing Custom query -- Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I want to execute custom query to get datetime of DB server `select Getdate()` using entity framework. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200617/how-do-i-use-sqls-getdate-and-dateadd-in-a-linq-to-sql-expression
The second answer.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework, rather LINQ. this is for LINQ

Comment: What's your DB provider? MS SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ObjectQuery<DateTime> date = new ObjectQuery<DateTime>("select Getdate()", context)
DateTime now = date.Single();
```

Comment: I am getting this exception "The query syntax is not valid."

Answer (score 2):

You can try somethink like that :

```
public static partial class ObjectContextExtension
{
    public static T ExecuteScalarCommand<T>(this ObjectContext context, string command)
    {
        DbConnection connection = ((EntityConnection)context.Connection).StoreConnection;
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();

        DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = command;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        return (T)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

It add the method "ExecuteScalarCommand" to the ObjectContext.
You just give the SQL request as parameter and the return type for the generic type.

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function GetDateTimeFromServer() As DateTime
    Using context As New NorthwindEntities()
        Dim dateQry As IQueryable(Of DateTime) = From bogus In context.Products_
            Select DateTime.Now
        Dim result As DateTime = dateQry.First()
        Return result
    End Using
End Function
```

You can use a query against a table (e.g. Products) and make sure you don't select any columns in the table as shown in the above code.  It is not elegant but it works.