# SQL GETDATE() in insert operations using Linq To Sql

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, datetime

Say i have the following table:

```
create table T (
    ID int not null primary key,
    Name varchar(10) not null,
    CreatedAt datetime not null default GETDATE(),
    UpdatedAt datetime not null default GETDATE()
)
```

and want to use with Linq 2 Sql. It perfectly generates type safe class with both CreatedAt and UpdatedAt properties non-nullable. Now i want to insert a new entry and want them both to be populated by a value from Sql Server, not with `DateTime.Now` which may differ. Is there a way to somehow send `null` to Sql Server without making the properties nullable? Also, i don't want to follow [this solution](http://www.spyriadis.net/2010/07/linq-to-sql-get-datetime-from-sql-server-getdate/) as it requires additional network trip. It's very easy with good old SQL - just omit CreatedAt/UpdatedAt columns in the insert statement and you're fine but what are my options with Linq 2 Sql?

Comment: Once you've solved your insert issue, you're likely to stumble when you want `UpdatedAt` to be set to `GETDATE()` on each subsequent update.

Comment: You're right. Possible solution can be completely ignoring values sent from clients and use triggers.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200617/how-do-i-use-sqls-getdate-and-dateadd-in-a-linq-to-sql-expression/201063) may be a suitable workaround for you.

Comment: No, it works with select queries only. I tried it and saw that for insert operations it generates extra trip to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this link. there is a attribute called IsDbGenerated which can be annotated with your LINQ partial classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.isdbgenerated.aspx#Y456

Comment: Wow! I'm giving it a try (need to find out how to automate this)