# GETDATE() in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

What is the alternate for `GETDATE()` in LINQ?

I got some workaround from the following post:

- [**How do I use SQL's GETDATE() and DATEADD() in a Linq to SQL expression?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200617/how-do-i-use-sqls-getdate-and-dateadd-in-a-linq-to-sql-expression)

Is there any ***better*** approach? In which, there is no need to an `ExecuteQuery` or a separate function call?

Comment: An approach which doesn't need an "ExecuteQuery" or a separate function call.

Comment: There is no extra function call, you just type it like that. It will be a single query. Check in SQL profiler.

Comment: Linq to SQL or Entity Framework or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can see with linq to sql the post you refer to is the way to go. I don't see how anything could be better. It's a pretty elegant solution.

With Entity Framework there is a possibility to use [`SqlFunctions.CurrentTimestamp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.currenttimestamp.aspx). Besides that, even when you use `DateTime.Now` in linq to entities (not linq to sql) it is translated to `GetDate`:

```
context.Companies.Select (c => DateTime.Now);
```

translates:

```
SELECT 
GetDate() AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
```

It's a different story if you *only* want to get the database date. In that case I don't see how anything could beat executing a query `SELECT GetDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

FROM VB

> Private Function GetServerDate() As DateTime
>
> ```
>     Using context As New DirectEDISQLEntities
>  Dim Query = context.Reports_MailList.[Select](Function(c) DateTime.Now).FirstOrDefault
>         Return Query
>     End Using
>
> End Function
> ```

And equal to

> SELECT   SysDateTime() AS [C1]  FROM [dbo].[Reports_MailList] AS
>   [Extent1]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
using (DataContext dboContext = new DataContext())
                {
                    var dQuery = dboContext.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>("SELECT getdate()");
                    return dQuery.AsEnumerable().First();
                }
```