# Calculate mins in Linq

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I am trying to do this to calculate the LastDate is more then 15 mins in LINQ:

```
And DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(tbl.LastDate).Minutes >= 15
```

I got this error:

```
Method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTimeOffset)' has no supported translation to SQL.
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200617/how-do-i-use-sqls-getdate-and-dateadd-in-a-linq-to-sql-expression)  about using `GETDATE` and `DATEADD` might help you.

Comment: `Entity Framework` or `LINQ to SQL`?

Comment: I am using linq to sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the EntityFunctions class to perform operations on dates, among other things.

```
And (tbl.LastDate >= EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime.Now, -15))
```

if you are not using entityfunction you can do that

```
DateTime oldestDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15);
```

...
then modified the where portion of the LINQ query

```
And (tbl.LastDate >= oldestDate )
```

Comment: EntityFunctions is not declare, I am using .net 4.0

Comment: I tried this => And tbl.LastDate >= DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(-15), I think it should be the same like your answer?

Comment: I dont calculate it in linq. After calcuating it do you get right answer or not? Calcutating linq may give you exception.